# have some issues with my bootstrap and css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to fix the logo on  the  navigation bar , I want to either increase the height of navigation bar and fix it without adjusting the image size amd When i shrink the website to mobile view , The Logo is seen below the collapse button . 
Preview of the website (http://threeguys.us/works/testing.html)

**testing.html**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo/logo.png" width="250px" height="60px"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rates</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Employee</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="call_button">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">call us</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div><!--jumbotron end-->
```

**style.css**

```
 .jumbotron
 {
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(images/car/car.png);
 }
 .container
 {
  padding:0px;
 }
 .navbar
 {
   height: 60px;
   background-color: transparent;
   border:0px;
   padding-top: 0px;
  }
  .navbar-header
  {
   width:70px;
   background-color: transparent;
  }
  ul
  {
   padding:0;
  }
 .call_button
  {
  margin-top : 428px;
  }
  .content
  {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top:0px;
  }
  .footer-nav
  {
  text-align: center;
  }
  .text_order
  {
  background-image: url(images/text_order/rectangle.jpg);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  }
  .text_order p
  {
  font-size: 20px;
  }
 .footer-nav li
 {
 display: inline;
 } 
 .footer-nav li a
 {
 padding-left: 50px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #f7ab00;
 }
 .footer-nav li a:hover
 {
 color:black;
 }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you wanting the collapse button to be on the right when it's in 'mobile view'? Also with the first part of your question, are you asking how to make the menu items bigger or the logo smaller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, comments and screenshots here are the following recommendations:

**Remove** this CSS code from **style.css** so collapse button is on the right (and not above the logo):

```
.navbar-header {
    width:70px;
    background-color: transparent; //don't necessarily need to remove this one but it isn't serving a purpose currently
}
```

To get the `nav` outside of the `jumbotron` whilst keeping the full image screen, perform the following updates:

**Update testing.html** to the following:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo/logo.png" width="250px" height="60px"></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Rates</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Employee</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">      
            <div class="call_button">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">call us</button>
            </div>
            </div>
</div><!--jumbotron end-->
```

**Update** your **style.css** jumbotron class and navbar class to the following:

```
.jumbotron {
    text-align: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(images/car/car.png);
    margin-top: -80px; //include this account for the height of the navbar and it's margin
}
.navbar {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0 120px; //the 120px value will push the logo and menu nav closer together. You will need to update your collapse breakpoints though. Adjust as you see fit.
}
```

If I haven't answered all your questions please comment below so I can update my answer.

Comment: How can i make the jumbotron fit the exact size of the image ?Image size is 1400 x 562

Comment: @BDS I've updated my answer to cover off how you can make sure the collapse button isn't above the logo and that the navbar sits outside the jumbotron. Were there any other issues?

Comment: you have been helpful. I need my website to look something like this http://threeguys.us/works/2_Website.jpg .Like the header has to be in the center of the image

Answer (score 1):

Modify the flow of your HTML. Avoid putting `nav` inside `.container`.
Use a structure like [**this**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGmJeb?editors=101)

This will put the logo inside the header as well as put it before the collapse button in mobile view.

Comment: I want the logo and navbar in the screen of the jumbootron.Some thing like this http://threeguys.us/works/2_Website.jpg

Comment: All you have done there is added the standard bootstrap nav without accounting for the stylesheet that @BDS included in his answer. What you have proposed would not fix the issue of the collapse button being above the logo in mobile view.